# Packer + Openstack: DomainID been asked even after providing it

Tags: openstack, packer, keystone

I am trying to use Packer with Openstack. I've set my enviornmental variables correctly still I am getting error while packer validation.

My json file for packer:

```
{
"builders":[{
"type": "openstack",
"region": "ap-au-1",
"ssh_username": "root",
"image_name": "kris-packer",
"source_image": "4ead4da5-efc8-48ce-bfa9-********",
"flavor": "2"
}]
}
```

I am getting below error:

```
./packer validate test.json
>>Template validation failed. Errors are shown below.
   Errors validating build 'openstack'. 1 error(s) occurred:
   * You must provide exactly one of DomainID or DomainName to authenticate by Username
```

As per documentation, I have set following environment variables before running packer code:

`OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID=
OS_PROJECT_ID=
OS_USER_DOMAIN_ID=
OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
OS_PASSWORD=
OS_AUTH_URL=
OS_USERNAME=`

I've also tried using OS_XXXX_NAME instead of OS_XXXX_ID and still getting the mentioned error. Can anyone please point what might be going wrong ?

Note: I am successfully able to run commands like `openstack image list` and perform other actions via CLI. Only issue I am getting is while using packer.

Comment: What's the output of `set | egrep '^OS_'`. Be sure to scramble any secrets.

Comment: Hi @RickardvonEssen, I am getting `OS_AUTH_URL=https://identity-3.my-url:443/v3
OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
OS_PASSWORD=mypassword
OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME=hcp03
OS_PROJECT_NAME=project name
OS_USERNAME=I323809
OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=`hcp03

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the Packer [documentation](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/openstack.html#notes-on-openstack-authorization):

> OS_TENANT_NAME or OS_TENANT_ID must be used even with Identity v3,OS_PROJECT_NAME and OS_PROJECT_ID has no effect in Packer.

I expect it to work if you do `export OS_TENANT_NAME=$OS_PROJECT_NAME`

Comment: Thanks Rickard, But I am getting this kind of error now: `* You must provide exactly one of DomainID or DomainName in a Scope with ProjectName`

Comment: Also set `OS_DOMAIN_NAME`

Comment: Just marked it as a right answer... OS_DOMAIN_NAME was the missing link... :)